# Searching Twitter via the new Twitter API V1.1

Tags: ios, json, twitter

I have an iOS App that used to sucessfully search the whole of Twitter for tweets on specific company names and this was very easy using the initial twitter API V1.0.
I used to download and parse the JSON starting with the following line of code:

```
NSData *JSONData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:searchURL];
```

The searchURL used to have the company name (In this case British Land Co) appended to the end of the searchURL as follows:
   http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=BLND%20British%20Land%20Co
All worked great!!

Now I'm using the Twitter API V1.1, i'm having to do a bit of re-work, so I have started using the FHSTwitterEngine.
The FHSTwitterEngine enables me to complete the oAuth sucessfully, where I save my user access token in my key-chain the first time I run my App and load my access token again on subsequent times I run the App. This part works fine.
I have successfully been able to use the FHSTwitterEngine to Post Tweets, Get a list of followers usernames...etc, but I still havent figured out what method I need to call within the FHSTwitterEngine to search for a company name like I used to in twitter API 1.0 above?
The FHSTwitterEngine method 'searchTweetsWithQuery' simply returns a list of followers!

Alternatively, does anyone know of any other library/API I can use to simply search Twitter for a company name and get back all the tweets on that company name in JSON format?

Thanks in Advance

Gav